# How to change the DOM element (background-color) in the iframe src?

Tags: javascript, iframe, background-color

There is a site [signal-exchange.ru/reg](https://signal-exchange.ru/reg), there are two iframe src in it. It is necessary to change in both iframe src, background-color. How to do it through javascript?

Answer (score 0):

iframe background is part of iframe content. You cannot change anything in iframe content if iframe targets to another domain.

Your site is
https://signal-exchange.ru/reg
Your iframe elements target to https://olymptrade.com and https://binomo.com/

Target location is from another origin so you get error "Access denied" if you try to access iframe content.

Read more about it here 
https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication